# window.PARAM vs window.parent.PARAM vs window.top.PARAM?

Tags: javascript

I need to access from several js files a global constant `SETTINGS` that is defined in a different js file.  Researching the matter, I've come across all of the following alternatives:

- `window.SETTINGS`
- `window.parent.SETTINGS`
- `window.top.SETTINGS`

What's the difference, if any, between these alternatives?  Is any one of them considered "best practice"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When the current context is the top frame, then [`window`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window), [`top`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.top) and [`parent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.parent) are identical.

Otherwise, `window` refers to the current context, `parent` to the parent and `top` to the top frame.

External scripts run in the same context as the document where they're embedded. So, use `window.SETTINGS`.